# Set background image at the decryption screen in Debian

Tags: debian, startup, wallpaper

I have Debian with full disk encryption. It's possible to set an image as a background instead of a simple console when system asks you for the disk decryption password?? To make something like:

[image: Disk decryption in Ubuntu]

In Ubuntu it's done as default. Can I do the same or similar thing in Debian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It's quite simple, you just need to install `plymouth` and set your favorite theme.